# Create PPT Chart based on Excel information

Tags: vba, excel, charts, powerpoint

I have a table in PPT that I copied over from excel and I want to create a PPT chart based on that information through VBA.  What I want to know is, is there a way to create a chart based off of that table and not off of the little excel spreadsheet that PPT automatically opens? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the chart is inserted in the slide from PowerPoint itself, the chart uses the PowerPoint DataSheet as its data source. You can open this PowerPoint DataSheet in Excel and link it to the Excel data you want to plot.

Alternatively you can make the chart in Excel based on the Excel data, then copy the chart and paste it (using onw of the link options) into PowerPoint. It will behave as a native PowerPoint chart (which is really a native Excel chart) but it will be based on the Excel data.